# Mongodb Index not used in case of $or query

Tags: index, mongodb

I have added created a collection `first`

and created index
`db.first.createIndex({a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1, f:1});`

and inserted data

```
db.first.insert({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6});
db.first.insert({a:1, b:6});
```

When making queries like

```
db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1}).explain();
```

index are used

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "myproject.first",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "c" : {
                        "$eq" : 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "f" : {
                        "$eq" : 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b" : 1,
                    "c" : 1,
                    "d" : 1,
                    "e" : 1,
                    "f" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1_d_1_e_1_f_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "a" : [ ],
                    "b" : [ ],
                    "c" : [ ],
                    "d" : [ ],
                    "e" : [ ],
                    "f" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "a" : [
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ],
                    "b" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "c" : [
                        "[3.0, 3.0]"
                    ],
                    "d" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "e" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "f" : [
                        "[6.0, 6.0]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "b" : -1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "c" : {
                                        "$eq" : 3
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "f" : {
                                        "$eq" : 6
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "a" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "a_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "a" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "a" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.4",
        "gitVersion" : "d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but when I use or query

```
db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]}).explain();
```

index is not used instead columns are scanned

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "myproject.first",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "f" : {
                        "$eq" : 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "a" : {
                                "$eq" : 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "f" : {
                                "$eq" : 6
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.4",
        "gitVersion" : "d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you've created a compound index on {a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1, f:1} fields but you're not following the order of the index. So your queries should contain all the fields in the same order that you've constructed your index. Since the field 'f' is in the tail end of the index, your queries will not utilize or even identify it

Your queries:

```
db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1})
db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]})
```

To make both your above queries use the index, you should build the compound index as below:

```
db.first.createIndex({ f:1, a:1, c:1 })
```

Comment: Thanx for quick response. The query `db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1})` does use the index as shown in the response object but the query with `or` does not.

Comment: Because your 2nd query is using $or operator, which must either have individual indexes on the fields or you build compound index in the right order